# How do I summarize data and bind new rows to an existing data frame?

Tags: r, dplyr, pipe, bind-rows

*Edited to give* `reprex` *in response to comments.*

I'm reading in several years of public temperature data for California's 58 counties. I'd like to create a summary, the daily statewide average, and **put those means in new rows on top of the data frame with the county data in a single, piped step.**

I now do this in three steps: (1) reading the county data, (2) creating the means separately, and (3) rowing binding the newly-created means to the data.

Here's a reprex:

```
#### Reprex ####
library(tidyverse)

df1 <-
  data.frame(
    name = toupper(c(rep(letters[1:5], each=5))),
    x = as.character(c(rnorm(25, 55, 10)))
  )

df2 <- df1 |>
  group_by(name) |>
  mutate(x = mean(as.numeric(x), narm = TRUE)) |> 
  ungroup() |> 
  select(name, x) |>
  unique() |>
  mutate(name = "Z")
  
df <- rbind(df1, df2)
```

Here is what I've tried so far, to no avail. Both throw the error message: `Error in UseMethod("summarise") :  no applicable method for 'summarise' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"`:

```
#Test 1
df <- 
  data.frame(
    name = toupper(c(rep(letters[1:5], each=5))),
    x = as.character(c(rnorm(25, 55, 10)))
  ) |> 
  group_by(name) |> 
  select(name, x) |>
  do(bind_rows(., data.frame(name = "Z", 
                             mutate(x = mean(as.numeric(.$x), narm = TRUE))))) |>
  ungroup()
  
#Test 2
df <- 
  df <- 
  data.frame(
    name = toupper(c(rep(letters[1:5], each=5))),
    x = as.character(c(rnorm(25, 55, 10)))
  ) |> 
  group_by(name) |> 
  select(name, x) |>
  do(bind_rows(., data.frame(name = "Z", 
                             mutate(x = summarize(mean(as.numeric(.$x), narm = TRUE)))))) |>
  ungroup()
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Providing a glimpse of the data, ideally a 10 to 20 row [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/9462095) is always a good thing to better see what's going on. My guess is that `bind_rows` doesn't like to be put within a (superseded) `do`.

Comment: The EpiNOAA package isn't available on CRAN and has specific dependencies that make it difficult to install from source. Please provide a sample of `df` by editing your post to include the output of `dput(df[1:00, ])` (or similar).

Comment: I wonder if something like this would work on your data. `mtcars %>% rownames_to_column() %>% { bind_rows(., summarize(., across(2:12, mean)) %>% mutate(rowname = "State avg")) }`

Comment: Many thanks for the comments. I had thought that, since both the ```NClimGrid``` climate data and the ```EpiNOAA``` R package are available publicly, that my example *was* reproducible. It certainly wasn't minimal, though! :) Does this ```reprex``` work?

Comment: This is much better, thanks! Even when data is *available*, it's very nice to put it in the question if it's not built in. Most people don't have the `EpiNOAA` package installed, and it looks like it's not even on CRAN. So it's actually setting a pretty high bar for people to begin helping you. With your edits, the bar is set at copy/paste, which is much much nicer both for people wanting to answer your question now and future readers with similar problems.

Comment: Understood. Yes, I definitely want to make it as easy as possible for people to help. That's common courtesy. Maybe I'll even get an upvote!

Comment: Thanks, @JonSpring! Your code works well and has the additional advantage of being compact. I was able to modify it to incorporate ```group_by``` for the ```mtcars``` dataset. Still working on modifying it for my original purposes (climate data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base R pipe doesn't let you use the object it's piping more than once--and twice is needed here, once to append to and once to get the means--but you can work around that by piping into an anonymous function, like this. (Note that I decreased your data size to 3 groups of 3 to make it easier to see and set a seed so the random number generation is fully reproducible.)

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(47)
df <- 
  data.frame(
    name = toupper(c(rep(letters[1:3], each=3))),
    x = as.character(c(rnorm(9, 55, 10)))
  ) |>
  mutate(x = as.numeric(x)) |>
  (
    \(dd) bind_rows(dd, summarize(dd, x = mean(x), .by = name))
  )()
df
#    name        x
# 1     A 74.94696
# 2     A 62.11143
# 3     A 56.85405
# 4     B 52.18235
# 5     B 56.08776
# 6     B 44.14263
# 7     C 45.14518
# 8     C 55.15131
# 9     C 52.47954
# 10    A 64.63748
# 11    B 50.80424
# 12    C 50.92534
```

I don't like this much, stylistically I'd do it in two steps, 1 to read and clean the data, 2 to calculate and append. The base R pipe's placeholder `_` requires a named argument, which `bind_rows` doesn't have, so we still need an anonymous function, but I still prefer this way:

```
## step 1
df <- 
  data.frame(
    name = toupper(c(rep(letters[1:3], each=3))),
    x = as.character(c(rnorm(9, 55, 10)))
  ) |>
  mutate(x = as.numeric(x))
 
## step 2
df = df |>
  summarize(x = mean(x), .by = name) |> 
  (\(x) bind_rows(df, x))()
```

If you don't mind the `magrittr` pipe, you can simplify Step 2 to this:

```
## alternate step 2
df = df |>
  summarize(x = mean(x), .by = name) %>%
  bind_rows(df, .)
```